# DataGrid. Struct property is not updated

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, struct

I've faced strange issue with Silverlight `DataGrid`.
When I'm binding list of structs (placed in `ViewModel`) to grid values are displayed properly, but for some reason changes that are made to grid are not reflected in `ViewModel`.

```
public struct ObjectSelection 
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public List<ObjectSelection> SelectedObjects
{
    get { return _selectedObjects; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _selectedObjects)
        {
            _selectedObjects= value;
            FirePropertyChanged("SelectedObjects");
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<navigation:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedObjects, Mode=TwoWay}"                                    
    <navigation:DataGrid.Columns>
        <navigation:DataGridFilterTemplateColumn Header="Selected"
            CanUserFilter="True"
            CanUserSort="False"
            DataType="Boolean"
            SortMemberPath="Include">
            <navigation:DataGridFilterTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </navigation:DataGridFilterTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </navigation:DataGridFilterTemplateColumn>                                        
        <navigation:DataGridFilterColumn Header="Dimension"
            DataType="String" 
            CanUserFilter="False"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Binding="{Binding Name}" 
            CanUserSort="True"                                              
            SortMemberPath="Name"
            Width="*"/>
    </navigation:DataGrid.Columns>
</navigation:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't define `ObjectSelection` as `struct`.

A `struct` is **copied** every time it is read from your property. That copy is used for binding. If that copy is then modified by the user, the original remains unchanged. I suggest you use a `class` instead of a `struct`. In almost all cases, classes are the better choice.

[Microsofts recommendation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx):

> Consider defining a structure instead of a class if instances of the
>   type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in
>   other objects.
>
> Do **not** define a structure unless the type has all of the following
>   characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (integer, double, and so on).
> - It has an instance size smaller than 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually I've already changed `ObjectSelection` to be a class. But I was just wondering if there is any meaningfull reasons for such behavior.